# Pull new item value on demand

Tags: zabbix

Looking for solution for zabbix to get fresh value (not from db) for `$itemid` via command line interface.

Force Zabbix server or proxy to poll a new value from a item.

`php command $itemid`
response: `value`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to get values from server or proxy cache? Query Zabbix agent? Force Zabbix server or proxy to poll a new value from a passive-like item?

Comment: Need to poll a new value

Comment: OK, I see that you edited the question to specify that you are looking into forcing server/proxy to do the poll. Unfortunately, that is currently not possible, added an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing Zabbix server or proxy to poll a value for a passive-like item is not supported at this time. There is a feature request to add such a capability: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-473 .

Comment: Can it be some not document script call from CLI and key values from $itemid, $hostid, $interfaceid values from DB?

Comment: No. One could try to patch partial support in server, but that's way out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can script around [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manpages/zabbix_sender) on destination host to send data on zabbix server, but it requires item key be "Zabbix trapper" type and periodical send should be configured on destination server scheduler.